# Unity 2D on some device, all images turns pink

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine, screen

1) The game works fine on many devices.

2) On Samsung j3 all images turns pink. (Banner is showing. Only all images are pink)

3) Android version: 5.1.1 Unity version: 2019.2.15f1

4) Here splash screen(empty background) and game menu screen;
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution;
Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Color Space
Change color space Linear to Gamma and select Auto Graphic API.
Of course linear color space better but Unity says "Unfortunately Linear Color Space is not supported by some mobile hardware and even certain games consoles."

Comment: Unity's default setting was Gamma for me, but selecting Auto Graphic API fixed everything. This is such an underrated answer for a solution that fixes the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer more of a suggestion, as far as I know pink is the default color when unity can't render something so my best explanation is that not all devices use all of unity's shaders so either you can edit shader files on unity for specific devices or you'll have to scratch off some devices from your list. Editing shader files is not an easy task especially for specific devices.

Comment: Actually, i tought the same thing at first. But i wasn't sure. I will wait a while.. then i'il probably do what you say..